# Adding option elements resets scroll position in select element

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I am building a select list with a large number of options with lazy loading. The data starts by loading a preset number of items, and then as the user scrolls down the list, more items are loaded. This is all working great.

However, when new options are added, the browser scrolls to the most recently selected item, or to the top if no item is selected (tested in Firefox and IE11). This is very jarring and annoying. I would like the viewport to remain in the same spot when adding options. This is not an issue with other HTML elements like divs or lis.

Here is the CSS:

```
#main {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

Here is the HTML with knockout bindings:

```
<div>
  <span data-bind="text: 'Loaded ' + items().length + ' out of ' + data.length + ' items'"></span>
</div>

<select id="main" size="10" data-bind="foreach: items, event: { scroll: scrolled }">
  <option data-bind="text: name"></option>
</select>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  data.push({
    id: i,
    name: "Item" + i
  });
}

function getItems(count) {
  var target = viewModel.maxId + count;
  while (viewModel.maxId < target && viewModel.maxId < data.length) {
    viewModel.items.push(data[viewModel.maxId++]);
  }
}

var viewModel = {
  data: data, // total data
  items: ko.observableArray([]), // visible items out of data
  scrolled: function(data, event) {
    var elem = event.target;
    if (elem.scrollTop > (elem.scrollHeight - elem.offsetHeight - 10)) {
      getItems(20);
    }
  },
  maxId: 0
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
getItems(20);
```

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wjra438/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting new items, you can reset the `scrollTop` to what it was before `getItems`. That will make the jump-to-top less noticeable, but I don't know how to prevent it altogether.

```
  scrolled: function(data, event) {
    var elem = event.target;
    var scrollPos = elem.scrollTop;
    if (scrollPos > (elem.scrollHeight - elem.offsetHeight - 10)) {
      getItems(20);
      elem.scrollTop = scrollPos;
    }
  },
```